# Why is the Mitzvah of Parah Adumah considered a reward?

Tags: tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, abraham, tractate-sotah, zechut-merit, humble

The Gemara (Sotah 17a) says that the Mitzvah of Parah Adumah was given as a reward for Avraham Avinu’s humility, and Rashi explains that it’s considered a reward, because A. It purifies. B. It atones for the golden calf.

The question is: A. what would be if not for the merit of Avraham Avinu - would one never be able to become pure? B. If not for the sin of the golden calf, would there be no need for the red heifer?

Comment: For A. amazing question, we have no para aduma now so try to imagine what would have been Jewish history had it always been like this? B. This brings to mind the point that we never would have died again had it not been for the sin. Where would we have contracted tumat meit?

Comment: @RabbiKaii, non Jews perhaps

Comment: That's a big perhaps